# Need a few built-in Symbols (functions) whose Options are a mix of Rule-s and DelayedRule-s

Tags: functions, options, rule, built-in-symbols, resourcefunction

This is for examples in documentation I'm writing for a `ResourceFunction["PrettyOptions"]` (look for it soon) that is close to completion. Asking for most common ones with varying numbers of `Options` `Rule`-s and `DelayedRule`-s which is why the request is for several. If you can supply a few (the more, the merrier) offhand, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

EDIT: I know this is a meta or community something question, however I don't know how to get there or how to transport this over. If you're an admin please move it there.

Comment: Here's the link to the meta site: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ if you need it. However, I'm not sure this would be appropriate there: it's not a question about the site, which is what would be appropriate for meta. I just don't fully understand what you are seeking in your question: could you expand a bit further?

Comment: I'm not even sure this is for [meta] it's very hard to understand what the OP is asking here or how are we supposed to help.  I have voted to close this question because it *"Needs details or clarity"*. The OP should [edit] the question to avoid or revert closure.

Comment: If the question was "How to find all or randomly 10 system functions for which Options[function] yields a list of both rules and delayed rules" then I would not see any reason to close it. One of them is Plot as can be seen with `Options[Plot]`. `Integrate` as well and probably every function that relies on the global variable `$Assumptions`.

Comment: @MarcoB i was hoping there was a meta or community wiki link somewhere on this page where i could port this post to there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: maybe use

```
filteredClass=FilteredEntityClass[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", All], 
      EntityFunction[e, 
       Not[FreeQ[#, _RuleDelayed] ∨ FreeQ[#, _Rule]] &@e["Options"]]];
```

Then :

```
filteredList = filteredClass // EntityList;
```

or for a random list of names

```
filteredClass[EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Name"]] // 
 RandomChoice[#, 50] &
```

```
{DensityPlot3D,Asymptotic,ListLogLinearPlot,DictionaryWordQ,Expectation,InverseFourierSinTransform,HumanGrowthData,InitializationValue,DiscreteMaxLimit,Dendrogram,FunctionContinuous,ExternalStoragePut,ListStepPlot,Play,CreateWindow,AbsoluteTime,CurrentImage,Area,SliceDensityPlot3D,KagiChart,DSolve,FeatureImpactPlot,ImageMesh,ReImPlot,CloudSubmit,DiscretePlot,ClockGauge,PossibleZeroQ,Solve,PopupWindow,TimeSeries,HighlightImage,ListVectorDisplacementPlot,FourierSinTransform,RegionWithin,SemidefiniteOptimization,ContinuedFractionK,GeoGraphPlot,RegionDilation,NotebookPut,WikidataData,FindFit,ResourceFunction,VectorPlot,ExternalStorageUpload,BlockchainBlockData,TimeSeriesShift,LogPlot,DensityPlot3D,VectorDisplacementPlot3D}
```

---

**Note :** *The options with RuleDelayed seem to often rely on global variables such as `$Assumptions` or `$PlotTheme` as such variables are susceptible to change. In other cases there are functions such as `StandardForm`, a pure form `FrontEndExecute` and there is also a `True` in the mix that I do not understand*

If you want the list of all system functions that have both `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` then one possibility is to use the Entity framework. As  an attempt to make this often obscure part of Mathematica a bit easier to understand I will proceed step by step in a series of questions for pedagogical purposes and a bit for my amusement.

The question:

How can I get a list of system functions for which Options[function] yields a list of both rules and delayed rules ?

- Reflex $\longrightarrow$ A question about data $\longrightarrow$ Entities
- Where should I look ?

The documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EntityTypes.html) has a list of entity "types".

These are broad categories like "Chemistry", "Language" , etc.

Another possibility is to use `EntityValue[]` to get a list of entity types.

Search for "Wolf" in that list you might find :

> "WolframLanguageSymbol"

That is the best looking candidate.

Now "WolframLanguageSymbol" is what is called an entity type. That type name encapsulates a list of entity classes and each entity class encapsulates entities. **Entities** are the fine grained objects like "apple" whereas an **entity class** is something more broad like "fruits".

So:

**Step 1:** What entity classes are in this type ? Will it really be of any use to me ?

To check the classes you can use:

```
EntityClassList["WolframLanguageSymbol"]
```

[image]

In that list

[image]

looks like the best candidate.

**Step 2**: What can we ask ?

That class encapsulates many entities. Each entity is a Wolfram Language symbol such as `Plot`. To check what we can ask we can use:

[image]

In that list we will see "options"

To check that that is really the options for the symbol we could take a random entity with [`RandomEntity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomEntity.html)

[image]

```
Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "InverseJacobiSC"]["Options"]
```

`(* {} *)`

Correct !

As can be checked with

`InverseJacobiSC // Options`

`(* {} *)`

For the reader that is not convinced, after trying `RandomEntity` a few times you might find something like `Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Fourier"]` which gives a non empty list.

**Step 3** : Filtering results

Ok now how do we **filter** the entities that suit the request from the original question ?

$\longrightarrow$ [`FilteredEntityClass`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilteredEntityClass.html)

One may define an [`EntityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityFunction.html) that filters out what we want.

So what do we want ?

Now comes the usual Mathematica code. We want a list of functions that contains  `RuleDelayed` and `Rule`. Those explicit names can be found with `FullForm`. How do we ask whether a list contains a pattern ? We could use `Cases` or `Select` and `Length` but `FreeQ` seems closer to what we want although it is the negation of what we want. Hence, we could use double negation, that is,

```
Not[Not[a && b]]
```

If we do not remember or know how that goes we can use :

```
Not[a && b] // LogicalExpand
```

`(* ! a || ! b *)`

So we can set up a filtered entity class with

```
filteredClass=FilteredEntityClass[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", All], 
  EntityFunction[e, 
   Not[FreeQ[#, _RuleDelayed] ∨ FreeQ[#, _Rule]] &@e["Options"]]];
```

Then use :

```
filteredList = filteredClass // EntityList;
```

For more information on entities I started a post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/276321/86543). I plan on updating my answer there with a concrete example and utility functions to facilitate searching in the future.

Comment: thank you. this is perfect.